# How to find the pci slot of an usb controller in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, proc, pci, sysfs

I have a nearly common Linux machine here. So, it has a PCI (*-X, etc) bus, on that some USB controllers, and I have USB devices on these USB controllers. Similar to this:

```
$ lspci|grep USB
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

And, there is also an usb device tree, as this:

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/2p, 12M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/5p, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=r8712u, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=MOSCHIP usb-ethernet driver, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/5p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
```

So, I see my USB controllers on the PCI bus, and also my USB devices on the USB controllers.

But I don't know, which USB controller number (on the USB bus) belongs to which PCI bus number!

How to find that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This information can be retrieved from the `iSerial` entry of the verbose output of the `lsusb`. Easiest is to pass the output to the the `less` viewer and search manually with `/`, or for example with `grep`:

```
$ lsusb -v 2>/dev/null | grep '^Bus\|iSerial'

Bus 001 Device 029: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
  iSerial                 0 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.7
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.3
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:1d.2
...
```

Comment: `less -piSerial` ;-)

Comment: Apparently `lsusb` when used in `lsusb -v | grep iSerial` dislikes to see anything else on the command line, resulting in: `Couldn't open device, some information will be missing` followed by the `iSerial ...`. The remedy is to use the `2>/dev/null` garbage can.

Comment: How do you interpret a value of `iSerial                 0` or `iSerial                 3 NA7DE4PN`? (these don't appear to be PCI slot identifiers)

Comment: @Alexander AFAIK, `iSerial 0` simply means that that particular device is not a usb controller/root hub. In the above example, the Huawei device is on `Bus 001` so its controller is whatever is returned by `lspci -s 0000:00:1d.7` (i.e. the `iSerial` value for `Device 001` on that same bus.) For `iSerial 3`, the following value (`NA7DE4PN`) is the value at index 3 in that device's usb string descriptor table - in this case, it probably really is the device's serial number. See §5.4.7 (String Descriptors) in Silicon Labs' AN249 or §10.1/§10.6 (Device/String Descriptor) of Cypress's AN57294. HTH.

Comment: @jaimet Cool! Thanks for taking the time to share :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool `lsusb.py` in `usbutils` (since version `002`) which shows this information right away:

```
strohel@mat480s ~ $ lsusb.py -ciu
usb1              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:00:14.0) hub
  1-2               046d:c069 00 1IF  [USB 2.00,   1.5 Mbps,  98mA] (Logitech USB Laser Mouse)
```

Here the `0000:`**`00:14.0`** is the PCI bus ID of the controller:

```
strohel@mat480s ~ $ lspci | grep 00:14.0
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another more GUI friendly option for those with a more visual learning style:

```
sudo lshw -html > /tmp/lshw.html
```

Then open this in a browser:

```
xdg-open /tmp/lshw.html  # Opens in default browser

# OR your favorite browser:
google-chrome /tmp/lshw.html

firefox /tmp/lshw.html
```